# Webscraping have incorrect result

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

When I scrape website it was total correct but have a lot of blank and some of incorrect data.

```py
import scrapy

class AudibleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'audible'
    allowed_domains = ['www.audible.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.audible.com/search/']

    def parse(self, response):
        # Getting the box that contains all the info we want (title, author, length)
        product_container = response.xpath('//div[@class="adbl-impression-container "]//ul')

        # Looping through each product listed in the product_container box
        for product in product_container:
            book_title = product.xpath('.//h3[contains(@class, "bc-heading")]/a/text()').get()
            book_author = product.xpath('.//li[contains(@class, "authorLabel")]/span/a/text()').getall()
            book_length = product.xpath('.//li[contains(@class, "runtimeLabel")]/span/text()').get()

            # Return data extracted
            yield {
                'title': book_title,
                'author': book_author,
                'length': book_length,
            }
            

        pagination = response.xpath('//ul[contains(@class, "pagingElements")]')
        next_page_url = pagination.xpath('.//span[contains(@class, "nextButton")]/a/@href').get()
        if next_page_url:
            yield response.follow(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse)
```

**Expect to have title,author and length as result of each audio book in every page.
**
**Result is: **
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/st2lm.png

Comment: You're fetching ALL `<ul>` tags below that div.  Clearly, some of those don't have the data you're looking for.  So, just do `if not book_title:` / `continue` to skip the empty ones.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a more specific selector for your product containers you will achieve the results you are looking for.

For example:

```
 def parse(self, response):
        # Getting the box that contains all the info we want (title, author, length)
        product_container = response.xpath('//*[@class="adbl-impression-container "]//ul//div[contains(@class, "bc-col-responsive")]/span//ul')

        # Looping through each product listed in the product_container box
        for product in product_container:
            book_title = product.xpath('.//h3[contains(@class, "bc-heading")]/a/text()').get()
            book_author = product.xpath('.//li[contains(@class, "authorLabel")]/span/a/text()').getall()
            book_length = product.xpath('.//li[contains(@class, "runtimeLabel")]/span/text()').get()

            # Return data extracted
            yield {
                'title': book_title,
                'author': book_author,
                'length': book_length,
            }
            

        pagination = response.xpath('//ul[contains(@class, "pagingElements")]')
        next_page_url = pagination.xpath('.//span[contains(@class, "nextButton")]/a/@href').get()
        if next_page_url:
            yield response.follow(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse)
```